# Clean way to remap casing of object variables

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've got a reasonably large javascript object (i.e. 50 keys) which I am retrieving from an API and want to remap the variable naming convention to our code variable convention. Currently, I am doing this:

```
let newObject = {
    myVar1: response.MyVar1,
    myVar2: response.MyVar2
    //...etc
```

Is there a clean (i.e. no `Regexp`), easy way to do this with `lodash` or something? I'd really love to have something like `_.renameKeys(response, "camelCase")`

Comment: Are you basically want to make them all lowercase?

Comment: I want to go from each word capitalized to camelCase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lodash provides a convenient way to do this by combining its `_.mapKeys` and `_.camelCase` methods:

```js
const obj = {
  MyVar1: "foo",
  my_var_2: "bar",
  ["my-var-3"]: "baz",
}

console.log(_.mapKeys(obj, (v, k) => _.camelCase(k)))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const newObject = Object.keys(oldObject).reduce(function(accumulator, key){
    const newKey = transformKey(key);
    accumulator[newKey] = oldObject[key];
    return accumulator;
}, {});

function transformKey(key) {
    //whatever you need to do to convert the key format
}
```